# pass 2 resultsets as datasource to a local rdlc file

Tags: asp.net, sql, reportviewer, rdlc

i have 2 tables:
Table 1: Scores

```
stuID  |Subject | TotalScore
1          maths    40
1          bio      50
2          maths    60
2          bio      60
3          maths    30
3          bio      30
```

Then Table 2: Summary

```
stuID  | Average | Rank
1          45       2
2          60       1
3          30       3
```

Now am creating a rdlc and a reportviewer.
How do i get the detailed scores for stu with ID 1 and also the rank to rdlc datasource and ultimately to report viewer all in a single datasource.
example:

```
 StuID : 1   Rank:2

Report:
subject |  Score
maths        40
bio          50
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two datasets:

- one for the summary, call it DsSummary: summary where stuID=?
- another one for the score details, call it DsScoreDetails: score details where stuID=?

Bind DsSummary to the Summary section

```
 StuID : 1   Rank:2
```

Add a table control below and bind the DsScoreDetails

```
subject |  Score
maths        40
bio          50
```

You use report parameters to dynamically change the student ID through querystring, dropdown etc

Comment: thanks...have been able to do this successfully in myasp.net pages...but not in rdlc...how do i add the 2 datasets to one rdlc?